# What are the solutions to implement responsive image lazy loading in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I tried setting a fixed height for the container Col or the LazyLoadImage tag, which did achieve the lazy loading effect. However, I cannot do this, as I must set it to 100% to ensure the image is responsive. Is there a way to achieve both responsive images and lazy loading?

```
import { Image, Skeleton, Grid } from "@arco-design/web-react";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import imgURL from "./pand.jpg";
import { LazyLoadImage } from "react-lazy-load-image-component";
import "react-lazy-load-image-component/src/effects/blur.css";

const Row = Grid.Row;
const Col = Grid.Col;

function ImageLazyLoad() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Row className="grid-demo" gutter={[12, 12]}>
        {Array.from({ length: 20 }).map((img, index) => (
          <Col key={index} xs={24} sm={24} md={12} lg={12} xl={12} xxl={12}>
            <LazyLoadImage
              src={imgURL}
              alt="Image"
              effect="blur"
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              style={{ borderRadius: "20px" }}
              placeholder={<Skeleton />}
            />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageLazyLoad;
```

Comment: Try: `loading="lazy"` on the `<LazyLoadImage`?

Comment: Added loading='lazy' but it doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 0):

Install React Lazy Load Image Component:

```
$ npm i --save react-lazy-load-image-component
```

Import the component:

```
import { LazyLoadImage } from "react-lazy-load-image-component";
```

Add prop to component:

```
<LazyLoadImage
  loading="lazy"
/>
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't have any effect

Comment: Are you trying on Safari? it's not supported there.

Comment: No, I'm using Chrome, and it's the latest version.

Comment: I checked the documentation of react-lazy-load-image-component, and it does mention that a fixed width or height needs to be set for lazy loading to work. However, my requirement is to have the images scale proportionally based on the viewport size, so I cannot set a fixed width or height. I can only set it to 100% to keep the images responsive, but this prevents lazy loading from working. Therefore, this seemingly simple issue has been bothering me for a long time.